# Is it possible to install usb driver in virtualbox without installing on operating system?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, 64-bit

I have:

1. A 64 bit Windows 7 OS
2. A virtual box of 32 bit

A driver installation which passes on 32 bit OS fails on the 64 bit OS windows 7.

I want to install the driver on the virtual box without installing it on the 64 bit OS. Is this possible?

Comment: Check the settings of the VM and check "USB". Is it available if you create new Filter? As long as the device itself is recognized by the 64 bit OS you should be able to pass it thru.

Comment: @Seth : The "Enable USB Controller" and "Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller" are both checked. The device is recognized by 64 bit OS but not in the VM. I checked device manager of both OS and VM (Showed up in device manager of OS as unknown device but did not show up in device manager of VM). I can create a new Filter only once the USB is atleast detected by the VM right?

Comment: No, below that there is a list field which allows you to define filters to pass USB devices to the VM. It should be available from the VM window as well on the lower (right?) corner. Essentially as long as the device is recognized in the 64 bit installation you should be able to pass it to the 32 bit VM, even without drivers fro the 64 bit version. You might need to define a custom filter with the information for the unrecognized device you get on your host.

Comment: @Seth: "Essentially as long as the device is recognized in the 64 bit installation you should be able to pass it to the 32 bit VM, even without drivers fro the 64 bit version" - This is exactly what I want to achieve. But I can't seem to find the list field.

Comment: Access the settings of the VM, Navigate to USB (the Top will have the USB 1/2/3 selection). Below that is an empty field with some buttons on the right. You can either "quick create" a filter by selection the one with the `+` on it or you can create a new filter (`blue dot`) and modify it afterwards (`orange dot`). As an example you could "quick create" on filter and have a look at what gets input and afterwards lookup the values for the unrecognized device. I'm not 100% certain this works but it should be.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is fairly simple.

In the Virtual Box:

Navigate to *Devices > USB Devices*

Click on the newly connected USB device and then the virtual box will proceed to installing it!

So I was able to install the driver on the 32bit virtual box without installing it on the 64 bit OS.